# ClubSandwich::conf_int in meta-analysis - SE formula does not give the same CIs

Tags: r, confidence-interval, metafor, robust

So I'm using metafor (rma.mv) and clubSandwich to compute a CHE model meta-analysis, but when I use the clubSandwich::conf_int function to estimate my cluster robust SEs and CIs, I noticed some discrepancies in the CIs when I use the SE to compute them in the usual way (lnOR +/- (1.96*SE)

Code is:

```
attbel_mods <- rma.mv(LOR ~0 + gender, 
                      v = att_var, 
                      random = ~1 | Study/es.id, 
                      test = "t", 
                      data = rattbel, 
                      method = "REML") 
 clubSandwich::conf_int(attbel_mods, vcov = "CR2")
```

Below is a sample of the output (not allowed to post a screenshot yet)

```
coef.estimate    0.437   
se.              0.390114
d.f.             2.78 
Lower 95% CI     -0.861 
Upper 95% CI     1.73
```

Using the normal formula to estimate a CI, I get LCI = -0.328 and UCI = 1.201

Can anyone tell me why this is, or if I've gone wrong somewhere!

Thank you!

Hannah

Answer (score 0):

in your formula `1.96` is used when critical values are calculated from `z-table` @ 0.05 significance level, however, here critical values are calculated from `t-table` as apparently, degrees of freedom is 2.78

so here it is:

```
coef.estimate <- 0.437
se <- 0.390114
df <- 2.78
t.score <- abs(qt(0.025,2.78)) #0.05/2 = 0.025 for each tail
LCL = coef.estimate - t.score * se
UCL = coef.estimate + t.score * se 

> t.score
[1] 3.329777
> LCL
[1] -0.8619925
> UCL
[1] 1.735993
```